# Default battle orders

Tags: endless-space, endless-space-disharmony

In late games I often use a VERY similar battle orders. Having many battles make me boring and tired to configure each of them for each battle.

Is there any way I can configure default orders?

Answer (score 2):

**There is no way to set a default set of battle orders.**

You have to set them manually for each battle.

For what it's worth, when I reach late game, I tend to build ships with a strong defence over a decent firepower. This means that you can play no cards and still find your ships unharmed ( or with minor damage ).

Any module that grants HP regen will help you with that strategy.